# Перебор вектора и разгрузка ЦП

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector

Основная функция программы, занимается копированием файлов из папки в папку на сервер, путем перебора каждого файла исходной папки в цикле. И стоит задача, чтобы функция принимала файлы-исключения, то есть не копировала их. Исключения я складировал в вектор. И встает вопрос как можно быстро найти соответствие элемента вектора и обрабатываемого файла. Такой способ работает, но он сильно подгружает ЦП, так как он находится внутри основного цикла функции.

```
if (!except.empty()) {
        except_it = except.begin();
        while (except_it != except.end()) {
            if (ps.filename() == *except_it) { // ps.filename() - имя файла
                ++it_source;                   // *except_it - имя файла исключения
                ++except_it;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: А что значит сильно подгружает? Под 100% на поиске? А разве основное время не копированием машина занята?

Comment: То, что вы делаете, по сути является применением стандартного алгоритма `find` - линейный поиск. Как вам уже посоветовали, вы можете воспользоваться другими типами контейнеров...

но что-то это все странно. Не должен такой простой перебор сильно перегружать процессор. Какой у вас реально размер вектора исключений? Дело в том, что да, другие контейнеры обеспечат асимптотику побыстрее, но коэффициент в `O()` у них обычно побольше. так что при малых размерах вектор обычно предпочтительнее. Словом, посмотрите, точно ли проблема именно в этом - линейном поиске.

Comment: @MaxZS Подгружает на 50%. Это критично, так как программа будет службой, работающей в непрерывном режиме. И в основное время она сравнивает на отсутствие файлов или устаревших, и только в этом случае копирует. А без этого цикла, максимум до 25% доходит и в единичном случае, так что средняя загрузка ЦП много ниже.

Comment: в подобных программах "бекапа" очень часто допускают ошибку - постоянно сканируют всю файловую систему - не поменялись ли файлы. Но просто вставка sleep(1) в середину подобного цикла сильно разгружает проц и не сказывается на скорости работы программы. Но правильный подход - это подписаться на обновления файловой системы - в этом случае она сама будет уведомлять о том, что файл поменялся. И нужно будет только проверить имя и скопировать.

Comment: Ну вот Вам @KoVadim и ответил

Comment: @KoVadim последовал вашему совету и написал функцию с помощью 'ReadDirectoryChangesW()', которая отслеживает изменения, только вот проблема в том, что функция стопорит цикл, то есть она ждет изменения, пока их не будет, цикл дальше не побежит

Comment: А пока изменений нет, то нет смысла и дальше по циклу бежать. Смысл проверять файлы, если мы и так знаем, что они не поменялись. 
Но есть лучше штуку - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - винда сама сообщит Вам, если файлы поменялись. Специально разработано для бекап программ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для быстрого (бинарного) поиска имеет смысл использовать либо сортированный вектор, либо ещё лучше использовать вовсе другой контейнер, например `std::set` или `std::unordered_set`. В случае неупорядоченного множества поиск будет выполняться максимально быстро (алгоритмическая сложность - `O(1)`).

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что сортированный вектор будет куда лучше любого другого решения. Конечно, нужно измерять, но я бы поставил на вектор.

Comment: @ixSci сортированный вектор лучше хэша? Хотя возможно на небольшом наборе и будет выигрыш. Ну и ещё, разве сортированный вектор будет лучше, чем `set`?

Comment: может и лучше хэша быть,— нужно измерять. Что касается простого `set`, то наверняка будет лучше.

Comment: По какой причине `sort_vector`, лучше чем `set`? То, что значения более локально в памяти расположены? С алгоритмической точки зрения и там, и там - бинарный поиск ведь.

Comment: Именно. Алгоритмическая сложность это очень грубый показатель эффективности, тем более, когда мы говорим о компьютере, где, зачастую, локальность побеждает любую сложность.

Comment: @ixSci странно, что у нас тогда ещё нет стандартного `sorted_vector` для обеспечения удобного поиска из коробки.

Comment: В стандарте много чего нет, и судя по тому, как он двигается вперёд, ещё много чего не будет. Правда, такого вектора вообще нигде нет, насколько я знаю(ну, по крайней мере, в массовых языках) и в этом есть смысл: отсортировать вектор не составляет проблемы, а вот иметь вектор, который всегда сортируется(после каждой вставки), может быть проблематично. Как я уже сказал, тут очень тонкая грань и на каждое применение, нужно проводить измерения, но если в программе есть узкое место, то сортированный вектор нужно принять во внимание.

Comment: Ваш ответ, кстати, не совсем верен: для `unordered_*` O(1) это для average case, но есть ещё и worst case, который O(n)

Comment: @ixSci худший случай это уже к вопросу реализации хэш-функции.

Comment: @alexolut спасибо за ответ, проблему решил сортировкой вектора совместно с бинарным поиском

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, список исключений менять не требуется, поэтому:

1. Отсортируй вектор.
2. Используй lower_bound для поиска в нём.
3. Сравни найденное значение (если что-то нашлось) с текущим.